# Using Cascading Dropdown Fields with a Large List

Tags: sharepoint-online, dropdown, cascading, large-lists

I am trying to find an OOTB method to use to accomplish this task.

I have a lookup field (Vendor #)  that needs to pick up the matching values whenever a Vendor is selected from its dropdown lookup.

For example, I select a vendor (Pizza Hut) and the Vendor # field should only give me the Vendor numbers or number associated with that Vendor.

I tried a Cascading Dropdown jquery that I found through Mark Rackley, and functionally it worked, but my list of Vendors and Vendor # is about 4800 and I would have to create the relationship in the background for each and every one.

Is there an easier way to do this OOTB that wouldn’t create so much time.

Comment: Try in infopath , it will be free from all codes/scripts. One thing to be taken care of will be to create a different list from which you have to make data connections for storing the values in cascading columns and using correct method of filters in the fields.

Comment: @ViperOrton - Can you elaborate on this or provide a resource for this? I am currently using an HTML form that I designed and have my fields directed to through JS. (Another Mark Rackley trick).

Comment: Are you familiar with Infopath ? Then i shall discuss or else it will be a long setup to start from initial stage.!!

Comment: @ViperOrton - No, I'm not familiar with InfoPath. I already have a form setup, and was going to use a lookup field, but as I said above I would have to form the relationship for over 4800 vendors.